# Update Drop Down List From Selection Of Another

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, webforms

I am needing to update the value of one drop down list based off the selection from a different drop down list.  The caveat that I have is instead of the drop down list containing the actual value displayed on the page, it is holding the id assigned, which skews my whole logic behind it!  I am wanting to update `ddlLocation` based off the value selected for `ddlCompName` on the page itself `ddlCompName` holds a text value like `On1, On2, On3, On4` but behind the scenes it is actually housing the value of `CompID`

This is how `ddlCompName` gets populated

```
private void GetComputerName()
{
  this.ddlCompName.DataSource = GetComputerNames(DBToQuery);
  this.ddlCompName.DataTextField = ComputerName;
  this.ddlCompName.DataValueField = CompID;
  this.ddlCompName.DataBind();
}
```

And this is the update I want to run, but doesn't work due to the numeric value

```
protected void ddlCompName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (VBS.Left(ddlCompName.SelectedValue.ToString(), 2) == "On")
  {
    ddlLocation.SelectedValue = "Building One";
  }
}
```

What do I need to alter so that I can make the update as desired?

EDIT --
@Nelak altering to SelectedText instead of SelectedValue throws this compile error

> 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedText' and no extension method 'SelectedText' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `.SelectedText` instead `.SelectedValue` if Text of each item contains  On1,On2, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the display text rather than the value then try this

```
protected void ddlCompName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (VBS.Left(ddlCompName.SelectedItem.Text, 2) == "On")
  {
    ddlLocation.SelectedValue = "Building One";
  }
}
```